# Java socket: two newlines faster than one newline

Tags: java, networking

I have a simple client-server application. Server is in Java, client in Python3. The server waits for a single client, then communicates with it for eternity in the following way. Server reads a line from the client, and the sends the message "yyyy" back. Thus, from the client side, the conversation could look something like this:

```
xxxx
> yyyy
xxxx
> yyyy
xxxx
> yyyy
...
```

The problem I have is with the speed of the communication. I measure the time it takes the server to read the client's request, and it is about 40ms. What is most surprising though, is that if the client appends an additional newline '\n' to each of its messages, the duration drops to ~0ms. What could be the cause of this, and how can I fix it so that I do not have to include an artificial newline to each client's request?

For completeness, I also provide the server side and client side code.

Server side:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;

class Server {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Clock clock = Clock.systemDefaultZone();
    try {
      ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket();
      server.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 4248));
      Socket client = server.accept();

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
      PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());

      while (true) {
        Instant start = clock.instant();
        String msg = sc.nextLine();
        Instant end = clock.instant();
        System.err.format("Took me %d ms to receive the message\n", Duration.between(start, end).getNano() / 1000000);
        ps.println("yyyy");
      }
    }
    catch (IOException exc) {}
  }
}
```

Client side:

```
import socket, sys

sock = socket.create_connection(("127.0.0.1", 4248))
fin = sock.makefile('r')
fout = sock.makefile('w')

while True:
  print("xxxx", file = fout, flush = True)
  msg = fin.readline().rstrip('\n');
  print(msg, file = sys.stderr)
```

We obtain the "fast" client by replacing "xxxx" with "xxxx\n". Note that Python3 automatically prints a newline after each message, so the the former really is "xxxx\n" and the latter is "xxxx\n\n".

Comment: Are you sure you always get 0ms with the change? I expected alternation between 40ms and 0ms: 40ms, 0ms, 40ms, 0ms, 40ms, 0ms ...

Comment: Yes, that is what makes it so surprising. As if the socket had an issue with rapidly alternating input and output, but not so much if the ratio is 1:2 ...

Comment: Interesting enough I tested it here but with python 2 (that's what I have installed) and java 8 on a windows machine. I got no difference between xxxx and xxxx\n - always 0-1ms

Comment: I could replicate OP's findings with Java 8 and Python 3 on an old linux laptop.

Comment: Tested on Windows10, Java8, Python 3.7.1. Always 0-1ms

Comment: Maybe it's a linux thing, I have tested it on LinuxMint 18 "Sarah", Java 8, Python 3.5.1

Comment: When I put `print("xxxx", ...)` before `while True` in the client, the measured time repeats in the following pattern: 40, 0, 0, 40, 0 0, ... With two `prints` before the loop, the pattern becomes 40, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, ...

Answer (score 0):

> I measure the time it takes the server to read the client's request

Not only that, but you also measure (at least partially) the time until the client sends its request.

#### Just a guess

The Python client is the bottle neck and cannot keep up with the Java server. The server's `nextLine()` always waits for the client to print something.
When you change `print("xxxx")` to `print("xxxx\n")` two lines are printed at once, which doubles the line output rate of the client. Now it's the other way around: The client sends messages faster than the server can process them and the client's `readline()` has to wait for the server.
Note that in the latter case, the messages alternate between `"xxxx"` and `""`. That's probably not what you want. However, you could use `print("xxxx\nxxxx")`.

You could test this theory by writing a Java client that uses `println("xxxx")`. Assuming the Java client is faster than the python client, I would expect the measured time to be less than 40ms but maybe a bit more than 0ms.

Comment: I have just tested this (with Java 8 both client and server). With a single newline, it is exactly two times slower (80ms). With two newlines, it's still 0ms super-fast.

The thing is, even if the client was slower than the server, it would not explain why processing "xxxx" and then "" is faster than processing "xxxx" only.

Comment: Then I must have guessed wrong. To clear up a possible misunderstanding: `why processing "xxxx" and then "" is faster than processing "xxxx"`. I did not talk about the time it takes to process something on the server, but rather the time the server spends waiting for input, that is the time the client takes to send something. With `print("xxxx\n")` two lines per loop iteration are sent; with `print("xxxx")` only one line is sent – but both calls should take around the same time. Also with `xxxx\n` the next input `""` for the server is already there before the server even sent its reply.